# Large collection published with filter and lookup on entire collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a large collection that is published with filter and pagination options, for example Clients.

Then in one moment in the app I want to lookup for a document that is not in current filtered page. How can I do it?

I would do it with two publications, but then all docs are sent to the client. I tried to use methods, but they are async, and I need a value from the collection at certain execution row, not when it will be available.

Comment: There might exist sever answers to your question, so you need to tell us a little more about your particular use-case. When exactly does the "lookup" occurs. How often you are planning to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Reactive Tables meteorite package.

It has pagination, sorting, reactivity, and searching built in.

Comment: Table works fine. The question is how to do the lookup over entire collection without publishing entire collection to the client.

Comment: More exact question would be, how to get data/document from server method in sync call. So it can be used in procedural way.